# Parsing doubles in an unknown locale in C#

Tags: c#, parsing, internationalization, double

I am writing a program that needs to parse a bunch of text files generated by some third-party software. Some of these files will be generated in France, where something like "1,5" means "one and a half". Other files will be generated in the US, where "1,5" is not a number, and "one and a half" is "1.5". Of course, "1,234.5" is a legitimate number in the US.

These are just examples; in reality, my program needs to deal with a variety of numbers in a  variety of locales; it needs to handle things like "e-5" and "2e10", etc. Unfortunately, there's no way to know ahead of time which file comes from which locale.

Is there some commonly accepted solution to this problem in C# ? I realize that I can write my own number-parsing code, but I'd prefer to avoid it, unless there's no other way...

Comment: Trial and error?! You could look into the lines where you expect problems and use `double.TryParse`(etc.). Then you (hopefully) know which culture it was and you can start parsing that file with the correct culture.

Comment: You cannot correctly interpret a string if you don't know the format it's in. How would you determine the format in your own number-parsing code?

Comment: Without any constraints at all the best you can do is a bunch of heuristics -- which is going to be pretty manual.

Comment: How about using a list of likely locales to iterate through and use for ``TryParse``ing?

Comment: @AKX `"1,234.5"` is valid both for en and fr. But their values are different.

Comment: @L.B: ``Console.Write(Double.Parse("1,234.5", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfoByIetfLanguageTag("fr-FR")).ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));`` throws "Input string was not in a correct format." for me.

Comment: "1,234" forget the ".5" in FR that is 1.234 in EN it is 1234.

Comment: If it's the same third-party software being used everywhere, talk to the vendor about the need to have a globally consistent export format. That's what support contracts are for.

Comment: @AKX You are right example was not correct but try this `Console.WriteLine(Double.Parse("123,500", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US")));
            Console.WriteLine(Double.Parse("123,500", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("fr-FR")));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your entire input file has been generated from one locale, you could look at the problem as having to detect the specific locale from the input file prior to actually parsing it. It's an extra requirement that results from the inadequate input files (which should all use one agreed locale or have a field to specify the locale used).

Language detection is not a complete solution as number formatting is not language-specific but locale-specific. Here is an example: If you detect the language as Spanish, would that be es-ES (Spain) or es-MX (Mexico)? In the former case, the decimal separator is a comma (1,23). In the latter, the decimal separator is a period (1.23).

The solution would be heuristics-based. The simplest is probably that if you know what your locale generally is (e.g. most of your users use the period), you could have an ordered list of culture identifiers and try then one after the other until you've found one that can be used to interpret all the numbers in the file. Could be as simple as starting with en-US and, failing that, trying with en-GB, since for numbers, there really aren't many more formats.

Comment: This is the solution I ended up going with; you're absolutely right about formatting being locale-specific. I sure wish we could get all the input files to use the same locale, and I'm trying to make it happen, but I am not the one administering that system, sadly...

Comment: Forgot to mention: if you are eventually in a position to mandate a culture, the most appropriate for data interchange (never displayed as-is to the user) is probably the invariant culture.

Answer (score 0):

This is maybe a little bit overdesigned solution, but it could work (In case your text files contain some text apart from numbers):

1. Detect language of your text files using a [letter frequency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_frequency). Google has open sourced a code they use in Chrome to detect page language - http://code.google.com/p/chromium-compact-language-detector/. I think I saw C# wrapper for this, but I can´t find it now. If you don´t want to use any library, it is not so difficult to implement it on your own. I have done some very simple testing of this algorithm and it seems that it is possible to detect a language from only about 15-20 letters.
2. Build regular expression based on rules for detected language (Or just parse it). This can be very complex problem, considering that there are many rules for decimal separator, number grouping, negative signs etc. But it is not impossible to implement.

Comment: The problem is that number formatting is locale-dependent, not language dependent. So if you detect language as English, you still wouldn't know whether to pick en-US or en-GB. As it happens, en-US and en-GB have the same number formatting rules, but that's just luck (they have different date formatting rules, for example).

Answer (score 0):

As you see from the comments your problem has no fail safe solution.
The best you can do is minimize the error:

Since each file (hopefully) contains several numbers all from the same locale, try parsing the numbers in file with all the expected **distinct** locales (i.e. don't parse with en-US and en-AU for instance as the number format for both locales is the same.)

After parsing you'll end up with either of:

1. A single matching locale.
2. Multiple locales.

In the second case test whether the results from all locales match (most/all locales parse integers without thousand separators and scientific notation the same way.)

If they match no problem, else try to employ heuristics to figure out the correct locale:

- Are the values in the expected range.
- If there is any other text in the file, you can do a word search in language dictionaries to try and figure out the language.

If everything fails discard the file and mark it for manual processing.
Your program should have a facility that allows marking files as being of a specific culture bypassing the heuristics.

Your best choice is to change the input format so that the file locale is specified somewhere, such as in the data, the name of the file or an accompanying metadata file.